# Unexpected behaviour of python list.append() in the context of inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, append

I inherit features from one parent class (*__Parent*) to two different child classes for constructing a nested data structure. The ***init**()* method of *ChildTwo* initiallizes the parent class using *super()* thereby setting *i_am_from_child* to *"Two"*. It then appends an instance of *ChildOne* to the inherited list *var*. It is this appending that behaves unexpected when using *list.append()*. The ***init**()* of *ChildOne* also initializes the parent class in the same way, setting its *i_am_from_child* to *"One"*, but without appending its inherited list *var*.

Therfore the list *var* of the instance of *ChildOne* stored in *ChildTwo*'s *var[0]* should have a length of 0 as it is empty. This behaviour is obtained when using numpy append. However pythons list.append() results in an instance of *ChildOne* beingg strored at that location.

```
import numpy as np

class __Parent:
    var = []
    i_am_from_child = None
    def __init__(self, which:str=None) -> None:
        self.i_am_from_child = which
        print(f"Parent initiallized by Child{which}")

    def how_long(self) -> int:
        return len(self.var)

    def from_child(self) -> str:
        return self.i_am_from_child

class ChildOne(__Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Initiallizing ChildOne")
        super().__init__(which="One")
        print(f"ChildOne: len(self.var) = {len(self.var)}")
        
class ChildTwo(__Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Initiallizing ChildTwo")
        super().__init__(which="Two")

        # two options in question
        self.var.append(ChildOne()) # this behaves unexpected
        #self.var = np.append(self.var, ChildOne()) # this behaves as expected

#####################################################################

X = ChildTwo() # instance of ChildTwo 
Y = X.var[0] # copy of ChildOne instance created by ChildTwo constructor

print(f"type(X) = {type(X)} and type(Y) = {type(Y)}")
print(f"X is from Child{X.from_child()} and Y=X.var[0] is from Child{Y.from_child()}")

# something weird with var happens when using diffent append methods
print()
print(f"ChildOne: self.function() = {Y.how_long()} should be 0")
print(f"ChildTwo: self.function() = {X.how_long()} should be 1")
print(f"Type of Y.var[0] is {type(Y.var[0])}")
```

Using print() I checked the correct sequence of method calles, additionally the types are correct. But *Y.var[0]* should be empty, i.e. *[]* and thus should have length zero. Commenting out the python append and uncommenting the numpy append statements in *ChildTwo.**init**()* produces the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're declaring `var` as a class variable, which is shared between all instances of that class, rather than as an instance variable. When you type `self.var`, python first looks in the instance attribute dictionary, and if an attribute with the name `var` doesn't appear there, it looks in the instance's class dictionary, where it finds the shared `var` attribute. If you want each instance to treat them separately, you need to assign that variable in the `__init__` method.

```py
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = []
```